# Questions related to DJ-ing

Tags: discussion

Is this website suitable for questions related to DJ-ing? for example 'How to do I record a mix with AmericanAudio VMS2?' or is there some other Stack Exchange website that I don't know of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's about recording, chances are it would be on-topic on [Audio-Video Production - Stack Exchange](http://avp.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I would like to ask questions about DJ techniqes like transitions, DJ software like Traktor, DJ hardware like turntables, MIDI controllers, mixers, lighting, speakers and amplifiers.